# how can i overcome the file not foundexception

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am rying to read multiple excel files which under one directory, but i am encountered an error java.io.FileNotFoundException: File path/** does not exist

```
          object example {
                 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
           val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Excel to 
                     DataFrame").master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

val path = "C:\\excel\\files"
val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
 .option("location", "true")
 .option("useHeader", "true")
 .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
 .option("inferSchema","true")
 .option("addColorColumns", "true")
 .option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
 .load("path")
```

Comment: hi guys, please somebody help me regrding above issue. i have to read multiple excel files in dataframe using spark-excel library

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("location", file)
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "False")
    .load()

val data = readExcel("path to your excel file")

data.show(false)
```

If you want to read a particular sheet:

```
.option("sheetName", "Sheet2")
```

EDIT: To read multiple excel files into one dataframe. (provided the columns in the excel file are consistent)
For this I have used spark-excel package. It can be added to build.sbt file as:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.8.2"
```

The code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import java.io.File

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel to DataFrame").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

// Function to read xlsx file using spark-excel. 
// This code format with "trailing dots" can be sent to Scala Console as a block.
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = spark.read.
  format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
  option("location", file).
  option("useHeader", "true").
  option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
  option("inferSchema", "true").
  option("addColorColumns", "False").
  load()

val dir = new File("path to your excel file")
val excelFiles = dir.listFiles.sorted.map(f => f.toString)  // Array[String]

val dfs = excelFiles.map(f => readExcel(f))  // Array[DataFrame]
val ppdf = dfs.reduce(_.union(_))  // DataFrame 

ppdf.count()
ppdf.show(5)
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: actually, let say i have 20 excel files with different schema under one directory and read in dataframe in one go..that is the challenge

Comment: you cant read multiple files in  one dataframe you will have to create the  additional dataframes for that.  one way I can think of writing N number of DF's based on files names present in particular directory is to load the directory as java path get each file name and path in MAP. iterate over the map and call the read method  to create DF 1 for each file

Comment: Building up on what @Aaron said, you can union the dataframes, provided the columns in the dataframes are consistent.

Comment: can you elaborate on what are you trying to do? are you thinking of reading all 20 files in one DataFrame? or have one DataFrame for each file? if you have worked on any code or some Kind of Output  that you can put in your question.  We are here to help but there has to be some level of effort on your side.

Comment: If it's mandatory for you to read all tables to one table the only option you have left is to create uber schema which contain all possible cloumns. Data which doesn't have a particular column will be populated with null.

Comment: val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    // .option("location", "true")
     .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    // .option("inferSchema","true")
    //.option("addColorColumns", "true")
    // .option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .load("path")

Comment: but  i am getting file not found exception...i tried with different options in load option  like .load("E:\\folder\\file1", "E:\\folder\\file2".......) and other option i tried was .load(E:\\folder\\*.xlsx) , still getting same error

Comment: @HadoopD your path  to xlsx file should  be // and not \\.. also .option(location , true) should be changed to .option(location, file(or your path variable)).. lastly you cant invoke multiple files using *.xlxs .. that just wont work. and if you are running in local you master should be set to Local[*] and not local[2] and leave the .load () as it is dont provide path there

Comment: val file = "G://excel//read//"
 def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = spark.read.
      format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
      option("path", file).
      option("useHeader", "true").
      option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
      option("inferSchema", "true").
      option("addColorColumns", "False").
      load()
val dir = new File("G://excel//read//")
    val excelFiles = dir.listFiles.sorted.map(f => f.toString)  // Array
    excelFiles.foreach(println)
   val dfs = excelFiles.map(f => readExcel(f))
    dfs.foreach(println)
// val df = dfs.reduce(_.union(_))

Comment: @aaron.. hi aaron  path to xlsx works either way// or \\. above code executes well. but i am not able to merge or union them bcoz differe file with different schema.

Comment: this the error i am getting . Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. DoubleType <> StringType at the first column of the second table;;
'Union

Comment: is there anyone can help me please.....i have to read multiple files(these files are with different schema so union does not work...is there any other way) in dataframe and write them into one sheet in excelspredsheet

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to create a super schema and read all of your files using the schema and then do union on your DF.  for the fields that are not in your  file they will be populated by null.  I cant help you any further than that